# Why don't we consider the normal force and the weight as external force?

Tags: momentum, collision

For example, if we consider the case where two balls on a frictionless surface are colliding with each other.It is a elastic collision but there is nevertheless the normal force and the weight of the object which acts on the system, so why are we saying that there is no external force acting on the system ?

Comment: Because they cancel each other out

Comment: @aK1974 But in general, if they weren't cancelling, we could say there is an external force, which is the normal force, action on the system, right ?

Comment: The comment by @aK1974 does not address your question.  The forces do often cancel and can be ignored, but that is different than saying that there is no external force.  If your system comprises the two balls and nothing else *then gravity and the normal force are both external forces, and need to be accounted for*.  To avoid confusion, especially in more complicated situations, it is advisable to account for *all* external forces, and that being done, *then* decide which ones cancel and can be ignored.

Comment: The sentence should be: There is no *net* external force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example that you suggest, collision of two rolling balls on a (horizontal) surface, you would be considering the conservation of momentum in the horizontal plane as there are no horizontal external forces.
Even if there were forces acting at right angles to the horizontal plane they would not affect the horizontal motion.
With this interpretation it is the word "horizontal" which is missing from the term "no external forces".

With motion only in the horizontal plane the net vertical external force (weight plus normal reaction) acting on the rolling balls is zero.
So the vertical momentum of the rolling balls stays at zero throughout and is usually not mentioned.

As with a lot of examples in Physics a lack of precision in the wording is used for the sake of conciseness.

Answer (score 3):

You are right.   It is incorrect to say that no external forces are acting on two rolling balls when they collide on a surface, and in many other situations when that statement is carelessly made.    The correct statement is that no external *net* force is acting.   Too often in the literature "net" is left out as if it can be assumed.   In fact, I just checked several Google hits on "conservation of momentum," and both referred to the absence of external forces rather than the absence of external net forces.

Answer (score 0):

Forces obey a linear superposition principle, as can be seen e.g. from the vector form of Newton's second law:
$$ \vec{F} = m \vec{a} $$
So if we consider an elastic collision on a surface parallel to the ground, we just want to look at the force components parallel to the surface, not the ones normal to it - because it is implicitly assumed that they do not matter or change.
If there is an external gravity field, it is however of course right to say there is an external force acting. It still might not be of any consequence for the problem at hand though (e.g. the collision on the surface will work the same way with and without the gravity field).

Comment: But I don't care whether in some experiments it didn't cause any problem (even the number of experiments is infinite), conceptually there is an external force, so I can not say that the momentum is conserved because mathematically there there is none.

Comment: Addition to that, assuming something, let say x, implicitly means that in order to satisfy some of the premises of the argument, x must already be satisfied.

Comment: It does not cause any problems theoretically/conceptually either. The momentum is conserved in the surface normal to the force - so the dynamics on that plane are free of external forces

Comment: of course, the whole problem is not free of external forces ;) and saying there are none in the direction normal to the surface would indeed be wrong

Answer (score 0):

In some dynamics textbooks, an example is given of a mass exploding into fragments in three dimensions as an example of conservation of momentum. This ignores the weight forces acting external to the system and is not an example of conservation of momentum?

Comment: Momentum is always conserved. Constancy is different from conservation. Conservation can include a "current": $\vec{p}_{final}=\vec{p}_{initial}+\vec{J}$ (the impulse). And actually, if you divide the collision problem into 2 separate pieces, the momentum of each piece changes...but momentum is still conserved, although not constant for each piece.

Comment: Bob, since you are new user in here, need to ask.Is your post a question to the answers, or are you trying to make a point ? Because, in those examples we always assume that there is no gravity.